# XML replace &amp; (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, xml, replace

I have a problem. In my XML file are some values with names which contains:

```
&amp;
```

How can I replace it with an normal "&" ?
I tried this one but it isn't working....

It's just the name so it doesn't matter if it is double ecaped or not...

```
<product>
    <title>Command &amp; Conquer 3tiberium Wars</title>
    <url>http://www.onlinekeystore.com/command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars-cd-key-origin.html</url>
    <priceEUR>7.99</priceEUR>
  </product>
```

My code who isn't working:

```
$string= str_replace("&amp;", ' & ', $string);
```

Greetings and Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a little more of your code ? how are you outputing the code etc.

Comment: why do you need to replace it? & is not a valid XML character which is why it has been escaped with &amp;

Comment: I want to replace it because I'm going to import this XML with WP All Import and I don't know if this will change it

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work. Tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code

```
$string= str_replace("&amp;", ' & ', $string);
```

Are you sure that you store the xml string in the $string variable?
Can you give us more code?

Comment: I'm totally sure. I mean I have a lot off other replacements and they work fine! (in the same function below the & replacement.

And yeah, I store it right:
 $word = $marker->item($i)->textContent;
    $escapedWord = escapWord($word);

Answer (score 0):

My Code:

function loadTitles($tagName, $path){

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load($path);

$marker = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

for ($i = $marker->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $word = $marker->item($i)->textContent;
    $escapedWord = escapWord($word);
    $marker->item($i)->textContent = $escapedWord;
}

$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save($path);
}


function escapWord($string){

    $replaceNothing = [":", ",", ";", "`", "#", "'", "´", "–", "!", "(", ")", ".", "@", "’", "+", "™"];
    $replaceSpace = ["-", "–", "_", "/"];
    $delete = ["Steam", "Eu", "Key"];

    $string= str_replace("&amp;", ' & ', $string);

return $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're showing us the lexical XML, which contains `&amp;`, but your code is processing the DOM. The DOM presumably results from parsing the lexical XML, and one of the things the parser does is to replace `&amp;` by `&`. That's not something you need to do yourself.

When you serialize/save the DOM as lexical XML then of course the process is reversed, and `&` is replaced by `&amp;`. If the serializer didn't do that, then the resulting XML would be ill-formed.